# Capture Video of Android's Screen

Tags: android, video-capture

Forget screenshots, is it posible to capture a video of the running application in android?
Rooted or non-rooted, I don't care, I want atleast 15fps.

Update: I don't want any external hardware. The intent is to make it perfectly portable and every frame is captured within Android OS. If it crosses the boundaries of the app sdk, I'm willing to go to OS level modifications but I would need a starting point.

Comment: I completely see what is being said here. It seems like the emulator should have the feature to redirect the current screen into a video file as well. I would love a feature like this so that I could make informative videos of my games and apps.

Comment: Did u got solution for this? if so please share with us. i too have to caputre  video of android screen.

Comment: @deepa nope there's no good way of doing this.

Comment: Check this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/

Comment: Is it possible to read from the hardware screen buffer ?

Comment: This application effectively automates making screenshots. Recording from my LG Optimus 2X (running CyanogenMod 7.1), attached to a quad core machine, it ran at a miserable 0.6 fps. Also it takes some tinkering to get working, as it is not up to date with the latest Android SDK. [See the notes on the developer's blog.](http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/09/installing-android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast-for-windows/)

Comment: Doesn't record video.

Comment: This is no good. It's too old. It has not even been updated for the new location of adb in platform-tools/. `05:17:22 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/Users/fakelove/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory`.

Comment: Use `ln -s ../platform-tools/adb adb`

Comment: It only take png screenshots. You have to use FFMPEG or Adobe After Effects to turn them into a video.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Android 4.4 (KitKat) and higher devices have a shell utility for recording the Android device screen. Connect a device in developer/debug mode running KitKat with the adb utility over USB and then type the following:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/movie.mp4
(Press Ctrl-C to stop)
adb pull /sdcard/movie.mp4
```

Screen recording is limited to a maximum of 3 minutes.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#screenrecord

Comment: is giving me response like  screenrecord: not found adb is out dated why?

Comment: Sounds like your Android SDK is out of date. Open up Android SDK Manager and download the latest SDK tools.

Comment: Is it possible to extend the recording time?

Comment: This is awesome.  I am getting some pretty bad artifacts on my `nexus 4` though.  I tried upping the `bit-rate` to `6Mbps`.

Comment: Just to add, this page has a package having a standalone adb + script "ScreenRecord.bat" which can be double clicked to start recording android screen video.. http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/record-screen-video-in-android.html

Comment: You can extend the recording time using `--time-limit`, followed by the number of seconds you want to record. [Reference here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord)

Comment: I get the error WARNING: linker: libsac3d.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
ERROR: unable to configure codec (err=-2147483648)
WARNING: failed at 1080x1920, retrying at 720x1280

Comment: @sulai The max is still 3 minutes: "The default and maximum value is 180 (3 minutes)."

Comment: Any backports for pre 4.4?

Comment: And FYI you can show a dot at the location where you tap on the screen with an option in the developer options on the phone.

Comment: Side note: this DOES NOT work on emulators! There is no mention of this limitation in the docs. It was divulged by the Google team here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682

Comment: You can specify bitrate as   "adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 6000000 /sdcard/demo.mp4"

Comment: Use bit rate, time limit & size options to change the quality of video
"adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 2000000 --time-limit 30 --size 1280×720"

Comment: If you want more than 3 minutes, just use `scrcpy`’s recording functionality. It has no limits. And even works over wifi, if set up over usb. It’s fast because it uses adb too.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question but since it appears to be unanswered to the OPs liking.  There is an app that accopmlishes this in the Android Market [Screencast link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ms.screencast&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tcy5zY3JlZW5jYXN0Il0.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that it requires root, btw.

Comment: Not functional on my HTC One.  Worked fine on my Galaxy S II, though.

Comment: This one does not require root. Seems promising so far...http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/installation/

Comment: droid-at-screen doesn't do video, @Fraggle. Just screenshots. It can do continuous capture, but at about 1fps.

Comment: Currently I'm using this http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/ to just show the screen on my mac, then using my standard tools (SnapPro X) to capture a movie from that part of the screen. Not sure what the frame rate is on ashot, but I think higher than 1 fps.

Comment: Worth mentioned that it costs money $$

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use a phone with a video out, and use a video recorder to capture the stream

See this article http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/02/recording-animations-via-hdmi.html

Comment: That's what I could have done but my requirement is to do everything inside android. Making it work on the go is the intent.

Comment: I think you're out of luck - the requirements to handle that much video encoding, on the fly, on a mobile device, is outside the scope of what most are physically capable of, Android (AFAIK) has no interface to access a stream, and even if it did, it's a potentially enormous security hole as an app could spy on the user.

Answer (score 4):

@taranfx, without more info I'm assuming since you are on StackOverFlow that you have the Android Developer Tools installed. If so you can run the emulator and then use one of the many desktop screen capture programs to capture your running application. [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) on the Mac works great for doing this. I am sure there are many good screen capture programs if you are on Windows or a Nix platform and I know there are some online services as well but I do not have any links nor have I used them. Here is a link for the reference document on setting up and running the emulator.[The Android SDK includes a mobile device emulator...](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Comment: Sorry? I asked for video capture in Android not on Mac or Emulator.

Comment: MWR is suggesting capture of the Android screen via the emulator

Comment: Not all aps can be run in emulator.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is also to use a screen recorder, such as SMRecorder. Instead of using the emulator, which is slow - especially for games and things you would want a video of, I recommend using a VirtualBox VM, with Android installed. You can connect the Dalvik debugger to it and debug you app there. If the debugger slows down you app too much, disconnect it to record the video. There are many links out there explaining how to set up the Android VM for debugging. I find it far better than the emulator. 
Now this does not take care of capturing screens directly on the device, in case you app uses the accelerometer, or the camera that are not available on the PC. For that I would use the android market app mentioned above.

Comment: for good measure: http://www.spkaa.com/how-to-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-using-vmware-player

Answer (score 3):

I guess screencast is no go cause of tegra 2 incompatibility, i already tried it,but no whey!
So i tried using *Z-ScreeNRecorder* from market,installed it on my LG Optimus 2x, but it record's only blank screen,i tried for 5min. and there i get 5min. of blank screen file of 6mb size... so there is no point trying until they release some peace of software that is compatible with tegra2 chipset!

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.3 has a new MediaCodec API that can be used to record from a surface.
See: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html
(scroll down to the section "Video encoding from a Surface")

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to record screen video directly from your phone or tablet if your device is rooted. I'm working on the [SCR Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iwobanas.screenrecorder.free) app. To the best of my knowledge this is the only app supporting Tegra devices (including Nexus 7) and Android 4.2. At the moment the app records between 9-18fps depending on device but I'm working to improve that. SCR Screen Recorder is still in beta testing phase so feel free to test it and give feedback.

Comment: Share your research how it can be done programmatically in android to capture the viceo of the screen silently?

Comment: @Iwo Can you share your research on how to record screen video grammatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Remote Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.nolesh.android.remotemanager). But seems to me it doesn't work correctly with devices which have big screen. Although, you can try [DEMO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.nolesh.android.remotemanagerdemo) before.

Comment: Both links are dead :/

Comment: @rahulserver, Google blocked them, because I used `Android` in name of the program. Soon I will publish them again without `Android` word.

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm desperately in need.So pls do notify here once u have published.

Comment: @rahulserver, I published them again and corrected links.

Answer (score 1):

AirPlay Mirroring and Screen Recording is now in [CyanogenMod](https://plus.google.com/110558071969009568835/posts/FZxCjDxJ5jZ) with Mirror APK (Beta).

Answer (score 1):

If you developing video-camera applications, then it will be good to know the API to use for video capturing:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

(the above link only show how the video recording can be done via Intent submission, not how the actual recording is done)

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/729988-android-app-development-how-to-capture-video

and if you want to write the "screenrecord" adb application yourself:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-cts-4.4_r1/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp

And the key recording action is done here:

```
static status_t recordScreen(const char* fileName) {
    status_t err;

<...>

    // Configure, but do not start, muxer.
    sp<MediaMuxer> muxer = new MediaMuxer(fileName,
            MediaMuxer::OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4);
    if (gRotate) {
        muxer->setOrientationHint(90);
    }

    // Main encoder loop.
    err = runEncoder(encoder, muxer);
    if (err != NO_ERROR) {
        encoder->release();
        encoder.clear();

        return err;
    }
```

For Samsung phone there is additional settings ('cam_mode' hack):

[CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH resolution produces green flickering video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225571/camcorderprofile-quality-high-resolution-produces-green-flickering-video)

More useful links:

[How can I capture a video recording on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't implement it but still i am giving you an idea to do this.

First of all get the code to take a [screenshot of Android device](https://www.google.com.pk/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=screen%20capture%20android%20stackoverflow&oq=Screen%20recording%20in%20android%20stackove&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i22i30.2341.5173.0.11147.9.9.0.0.0.0.381.1631.2-5j1.6.0.ckp,kpns=1000,kpnr=120...0...1.1.47.serp..5.4.1145.AolQF-lxRiw). And Call the same function for creating Images after an interval of times. Add then find the code to create [video from frames/images](https://www.google.com.pk/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=make%20video%20from%20images%20android%20stackoverflow&oq=make%20video%20from%20images%20android%20stackoverflow&gs_l=serp.3...2226.17503.0.17686.20.19.1.0.0.0.270.2537.2-11.11.0.ckp,kpns=1000,kpnr=120...0...1.1.47.serp..12.8.1826.i-7WquzFAek).

**Edit**

see [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/create-video-from-image-frames-with-xuggler/) also and modify it according to your screen dimension .The main thing is to divide your work into several small tasks and then combine it as your need.

[FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android) is the best way to do this. but once i have tried but it is a very long procedure. First you have to download cygwin and Native C++ library and lot of stuff and connect then you are able to work on FFMPEG (it is built in C++).

Comment: I did same as you suggested from taking images after an interval of time or without no interval, I have scrolling view in which i am doing scrolling and in another thread i am capturing screen area, but a same capturing is returns for 6-7 images and than another different area is captured. I need complete sequence of images.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record the user navigation so you can test UI and other things, I recommend you to use [TestFairy](http://testfairy.com/)

It allows you to send the apk to some test users by email and see a video with all the sessions in the app and even the app crashes and device stats.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Lollipop (5) a [new feature has been added](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) which allows screen capture [which is explained here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture)

[Here is an example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/bf1e262/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java)

Call startActivityForResult like this

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.getScreenCaptureIntent(), PERMISSION_CODE);
```

Then capture the result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != PERMISSION_CODE) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
        return;
    }
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "User denied screen sharing permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
    mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but what about [ASC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benzul.asc)?

Comment: Due to incompatibility with Tegra-powered devices? .. yeah.. i got a Asus Transformer :C

Comment: It requires running an 'activator' on the PC/Mac, but is unsigned and doesn't explain what it does nor how to do the 'activation' manually. It sounds like a security risk and threat vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a PC then you can run [My Phone Explorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/) on the PC, the [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) on the phone, set the screen capture to refresh continuously, and use [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) to capture a custom rectangular area of your screen over the My Phone Explorer window with your own capture rate. Then convert to a FLV in Wink, then convert from Flash video to MPG with [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/).

Comment: It should be added that "PC" here means some sort of Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the app, but I've seen [Rec.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spectrl.rec&hl=en%20%22Rec.%22%20as%20an%20app%20to%20do%20this,%20but%20requires%20rooting%20the%20phone.) referenced as a way to do this, but you need root the phone.

Answer (score 0):

11 years later, I can offer a better answer. I can see that people still visit this answer.

scrcpy

It's available in the package manager of Ubuntu 22.04, at least, presumably also in Debian and other distros.

It requires that you have an adb connection. If you are connecting over tcp, you need to do an "adb connect <ip_address>:5555" first.