# Android: CamcorderProfile. QUALITY_HIGH returns 1080p instead of 2160p on Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I've written application which records video. I always use highest available resolution:

```
mediaRecorder.setProfile( CamcorderProfile.get( cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH ) );
```

Unfortunately in case of Samsung Galaxy S5 video is recorded in 1080p instead of 2160p (which is the highest possible resolution on this device).

Does anybody know why does it happen and how to force Android to use highest resolution?
I don't want to 'hardcode' it by setting resolution manually but just always use the highest one.

Thanks!

Comment: QUALITY_HIGH returns the highest resolution on the device so you're doing it right.  The problem seems to be in the phone.

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225571/camcorderprofile-quality-high-resolution-produces-green-flickering-video see the answer from `jagsaund` - CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH returns the highest possible supported camera resolution. Ensure you are using the correct camera id (front vs. back) -- maybe the back facing camera supports 1080p but the front facing camera does not?

Comment: jagsaund: Yes, I'm sure that I'm using right camera. On all other devices resolution is highest possible.

Comment: The same thing happens to me in the 4 tab

Comment: maybe you have a preview size set somewhere in your code.