# How to get a list of supported camcorder profiles in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

The resolution of a recorded video is set according to `CamcorderProfile` which is passed to a `MediaRecorder` object. The profiles are identified by quality constants: `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P, etc.`

The problem is that I can't get a list of supported recording resolutions/profiles. I can use `hasProfile` method, but it only checks if a given profile is supported, while I would prefer to have a full list of such profiles.

There is a method in `Camera.parameters` called `getSupportedVideoSizes()`, which should return what I need, but it returns null, which I guess means that I should use `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` instead. But there is no correspondance between the list of preview sizes and profiles.

Comment: I think here is the solution for your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225571/camcorderprofile-quality-high-resolution-produces-green-flickering-video