# MediaRecorder with 360p Recording

Tags: android, pixel, resolution, mediarecorder

I don't know this is a bug of `MediaRecorder`/ `CamcorderProfile` or not but let me explain my situation.

**My Goal for app**
 - I want to make one `camera` module which has basic only front camera not back
 - Also it can record only `360p`(540 * 360 resolution).

**What I do for code**

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(mCameraId,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mCaptureSize.getWidth(), mCaptureSize.getHeight()); 
 //width = 360 & height = 540  it will crash 
//width = 480 & height = 720 it will allow 
    .....
    .....
```

**Where I stuck**

So, for pixel of video, I have to change
[CamcorderProfile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html)

> CamcorderProfile.get(mCameraId,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)

-CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_360P  is missing so how can I get video resolution 540*360

[image]

-or I have missed something?

Comment: "Also it can record only 360p(540 * 360 resolution)" -- there is no requirement that a device support that resolution for either camera, let alone the front-facing camera. And, as you note, it is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Then can u plz guide me how can I achieve I am new bee for  this  multimedia android topic @CommonsWare  any little hint or something else

Comment: @CommonsWare explain that a device support that resolution. Check this i hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225571/camcorderprofile-quality-high-resolution-produces-green-flickering-video

Comment: 360p is equals to 480 x 360

Comment: Achieve *what*? Use `CamcorderProfile` and `hasProfile()` to see what profiles are supported. Choose one. Record using that profile.

Comment: Thats means suppose i wanna 720*480 px so i have to check hasProfile() first for device?

Comment: mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
     .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA));