# How to convert a video into an image sequence

Tags: android, image, sequence

I'm creating a tutorial for my app and I would like to add an animated image just like the one below, but I don't know how I achieve that. If you could suggest me an app or how can I do the same it would be very helpful. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Animated app as in what sense?? or do you want to record your app screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture Video of Android's Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382212/capture-video-of-androids-screen)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1 out%d.png
```

Output one image every second, named out1.png, out2.png, out3.png, etc.