# How to store Video in Android?

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-file

I use the below intent to call the camera application to capture video. This is working fine. But On the **onActivityResult** I am not sure how to store this into a file in `SD card`. Can some one give me a sample to do this. Thank you.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

1. Also I want to show a preview of the video in my application and then if the user clicks the preview i need to open it up in a video player. Can I get some help on that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MediaRecorder class to capture video and store it somewhere in the sdcard.

Pls have a look at the link below which might help you

[How can I capture a video recording on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/android-video-recording-sample)

Thanks!