# Android camera video recording

Tags: android, android-camera

I have some code on the following link to record the video
[How can I capture a video recording on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/android-video-recording-sample)

it works fine but I want to start preview my camera before start the recording. 
I have try to add the

```
recorder.setCamera(Camera.open());
```

but it doesn't work. Please suggest me what should I add for start preview before recording.

regards

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Camera object to start the preview and then stop it before using the MediaRecorder (take a look here to see how to use the camera: [Camera Tutorial)](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx)

You also have the android camera app in order to see how to combine the Camera API and the MediaRecorder API. It is a great reference for this stuff:
[Camera App](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=tree)

Justo  install git and download the code.
You want to look on:

1. VideoCamera
2. CameraHandler (or something like this)

Good luck.