# MediaRecorder issue - throws FileNotFoundException when I try to write to sdcard

Tags: android, audio-recording, permission-denied, mediarecorder

Here is the exact exception that's thrown:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/example.mp4 (Permission denied)
```

I literally copied and pasted example code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379320/813207). In addition, I also added this little bit of code to format my path correctly:

```
private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }
```

Here are the permissions included in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
```

Am I missing something completely obvious or is it something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check if the phone is in "Mass Storage Mode".
When USB cable is connected in this mode, you cannot access files on /sdcard.