# Change format of ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android, video, format

Is there a way to either select the video format output of the video recorded by setting an Intent extra? Or can I do it in a post-recording processing function? What I'm trying to do is take the video that I just recorded and send it in an MMS message using an ACTION_SEND intent, but it won't take the .mp4 format that the camera is storing it as.

How would I go about doing this?

Edit: This is what my recording code is:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(videoIntent, VIDEO_ACTIVITY);
```

Comment: are you collecting the video from the device's native video recorder? Or are you recording the video yourself in your app?

Comment: I'm using the native video recorder using an ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent

Comment: I think your best bet is to write your own video recording activity which allows you to set whatever settings you wish. See if this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/android-video-recording-sample

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping to not have to go down that road...oh well, looks like I'll end up having to give that a try.

Comment: as per the answer below, before you waste any time constructing your own recorder (it's not that big a hassle, the code in that link is works pretty much out of the box), try making a tiny video and saving it on the sdcard and sending *that... see what the limitations are and then build to those.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try and get back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any of the following extra's to the intent `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` although I'm quite sure this is not what your looking for exactly, but lets dig into it a little bit more.

```
EXTRA_OUTPUT
EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY
EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT
EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT
```

While I don't think there is a protocol limitation on the file size for mms' maybe there is a limit in Android (<strike>just speculating here</strike>between 300kb & 500kb although some devices allow you to increase it in message settings) so try sending a video with a lower quality and perhaps a size limit to check if that solves your problem.

The reason I'm saying this is because I remember something similar a while ago, and the error message was something like (quoting my memory):

> Sorry, you can not add this video to your message

Which turned out to be the size limitation I mentioned, not encoding or file type.

**Update**

[Looking at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY) I found out a mention to mms on the MediaStore's stuff, particularly on the `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` one, here it is:

> The name of the Intent-extra used to control the quality of a recorded video. This is an integer property. **Currently value 0 means low quality, suitable for MMS messages**, and value 1 means high quality. In the future other quality levels may be added.

Comment: Thats the exact error message I'm getting, "Sorry, you can not add this video to your message". I have this set already:   videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);

Comment: Then it probably means the filesize is too big, try with a really really small video of low quality and see if it work.

Comment: I recorded at ~50 kb, and I'm getting the same error. Note: this is only for SMS/MMS apps, not email/facebook/etc

Comment: Maybe storing it locally before sending it on an mms?Have you tried a local file instead of the streamed one from the camera intent?

Comment: Yes, I'm storing it in a local on the sdcard, and sending it to mms via that file.

Comment: I know this isn't your preferred answer either, but you can always send the video through a 3rd party aggregator, who will take videos of up to 20 megs and transcode them for every handset and so forth.