# Android code to record a video using remote IP camera which is accessed by using a url

Tags: android

Here are some links which tell about video recording:

[How can I capture a video recording on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/android-video-recording-sample)
https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample

and there are also many links which tell about video recording but got no any clue how to use the remote IP camera to record video.
By using different samples on stackoverflow I become able to take picture and save on sdcard but couldn't record video.

If any one has any idea or code along with required files I will be thankful.

For example the url I am using  where the IP camera is available is given below:

http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&amp%3bdummy=1333689998337

Here is the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" >
    </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" >
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <view
            android:id="@+id/mv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            class="com.apps.GrahamConst.MjpegView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/navbar" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/previous" >
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/main" >
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/next" >
    </ImageButton>
  </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Activity

```
    public class CameraDetails2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private MediaScannerConnection m_pScanner;
String drawable = null;
private MjpegView mv;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private HashMap<String, String> item;
private int id = -1;
private WindowManager winMan;
boolean recording = false;
MediaRecorder recorder;

int bytearraysize = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    winMan = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (winMan != null) {
        int orientation = winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
        if (orientation == 0) {
            // Portrait
            setContentView(R.layout.cameradetails);
        } else if (orientation == 1) {
            // Landscape
            setContentView(R.layout.cameradetailsl);
        }
    }

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCam);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);

    id = Integer.valueOf(b.get("id").toString());
    item = listarrayadapter.cameraList.get(Integer.valueOf(id));
    mv = (MjpegView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
    try {
        getVal(item.get("cameraLink"));
        // getVal("http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg 
                 /video.cgi?resolution=800x600&amp%3bdummy=1333689998337");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offline);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    // if(recording)
    // {
    // getVal("http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg
             /video.cgi?resolution=800x600&amp%3bdummy=1333689998337");
    // }

    super.onResume();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dialog.dismiss();
    mv.stopPlayback();
}

private void getVal(final String url) {
    Log.i("URL===", url);

    updateButtons();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, null, true);
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    };

    Thread checkUpdate = null;
    checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(url));
            mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    checkUpdate.start();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int btn = v.getId();

    if (btn == R.id.btnMain) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(CameraDetails2.this, CamerasList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    if (btn == R.id.btnNext) {

        id += 1;
        Intent myintent = new Intent(CameraDetails2.this,
                CameraDetails.class);

        myintent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(myintent);
        finish();

    }
    if (btn == R.id.btnPrevious) {
        id -= 1;
        Intent myintent = new Intent(CameraDetails2.this,
                CameraDetails.class);
        myintent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(myintent);
        finish();

    }
    if (btn == R.id.btnCam) {
        if (mv != null) {
            Date dt = new Date();
            int years = dt.getYear();
            int month = dt.getMonth();
            int day = dt.getDay();
            int hours = dt.getHours();
            int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
            int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
            final String filename = years + "" + month + "" + day + ""
                    + hours + "" + minutes + "" + seconds;

            try {

                Bitmap image = MjpegView.savebmp;

                File SDCardRoot = 
                       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        SDCardRoot.toString() + "/" + 
                             filename + ".jpg");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new 
                     BufferedOutputStream(
                        fileOutputStream);
                int quality = 95;
                image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);
                final String szFile = SDCardRoot.toString() + "/"
                        + filename + ".jpg";

                m_pScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(this,
                        new MediaScannerConnectionClient() 
           {
                            public void 
            onMediaScannerConnected() {
                                m_pScanner

                      .scanFile(szFile, null /* mimeType */);
                            }

                            public void 
       onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                if 
        (path.equals(szFile)) {

            CameraDetails2.this

        .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "Image Saved.",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                            .show();

                                                }
                                            });

                          m_pScanner.disconnect();
                                }
                            }

                        });
                m_pScanner.connect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if (btn == R.id.btnVideo) {
        if (recording) {

            // stop and save

            recording = false;
            MjpegInputStream.isrecording = false;
            List<byte[]> bytelist = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
            ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream> byteArrayStream =
                            MjpegInputStream.byteArrayStream;
            for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayStream.size(); i++) {

                byte[] templist      
                                   =byteArrayStream.get(i).toByteArray();
                bytelist.add(templist);

            }

            for (int j = 0; j < bytelist.size(); j++) {
                bytearraysize += bytelist.get(j).length;
            }

            byte[] totalbytes = new byte[bytearraysize];
            int f = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < bytelist.size(); j++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < bytelist.get(j).length; a++) {
                    totalbytes[f] = bytelist.get(j)[a];
                    f++;
                }
            }

            Log.e("num of bytes", "" + totalbytes.length);

            // Byte[] bytes = bytelist.toArray(new 
                                     //Byte[bytelist.size()]);

            try {
                writeToFile(totalbytes, "" + 
                  System.currentTimeMillis());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            recording = true;
            MjpegInputStream.isrecording = true;
            // onResume();
            // start recording
        }

        // recorder=new MediaRecorder();
        // try {
        // recorder.prepare();
        // } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // finish();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // finish();
        // }
        //
        // //recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        // // recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        //
        // //
        // //
        // // CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
        // // .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        // // recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        // recorder.setVideoSource(mv.getId());
        // recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
        // recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        // recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }

}

public void writeToFile(byte[] bytes, String videoname) throws IOException {
    try {
        Log.e("num of bytes to be saved", "" + bytes.length);
        String path = "/sdcard/" + videoname + ".mp4";
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        stream.write(bytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateButtons() {
    ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    ImageButton btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    if (id == 0) {
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if (id == listarrayadapter.cameraList.size() - 1) {
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

    }
```

Comment: any answer on this thread ? Im having the same issue. thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366835/how-to-capture-record-clip-from-video-url-in-android-and-save-to-phone/27565298#27565298

Comment: Any answer on this thread?