# How to capture H.264 encoded frame in android?

Tags: android, video, native, h.264, codec

I understand like, there are two ways of capturing video in android.

1) using SurfaceView API

2) using MediaRecorder API

I want to capture the H.264 encoded frames using the Android (3.0+) 's default encoder to send it over network using RTP.

While using preview callbacks with SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder classes, we are able to get raw frames shown as preview to the user. We were getting the frames in "onPreviewFrame" method of "PreviewCallback" class.
But, those frames are H.264 encoded. 
So, I tried with "MediaRecorder" API to set H.264 encoding and "SurfaceView" to get the preview frames. 
In this case, the previewcallbacks are not getting called.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this. Our main aim is to get the H.264 encoded frame (which hass been encoded using android's default codec). 
Ref: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655244/698316 
2) Similar issue: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/214422

Can you suggest a way to capture the H.264 encoded frames using android's default H.264 codec support.

Answer (score 3):

See Spydroid http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

Basically you let the video encoder write a .mp4 with H.264 to a special file descriptor that calls your code on write. Then strip off the MP4 header and turn the H.264 NALUs into RTP packets.