# Android mediarecording error start failed -19 runTimeException

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, runtimeexception, android-mediarecorder

I'm experiencing a problem with my mediarecording. I'm trying to use the front camera to recored. This gives me an error(but the preview is working). Whenever I use the back camera everything works just fine, I think this is very weird. What could be the problem and what could be the solution? My code and errors are shown below.

Edit. Recording with a vga front camera seems not to work. How is this possible? Although recording with HTC camera app IS possible.

Thanking you in advance.

```
protected void startRecording() throws Exception 
{
    mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);


    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 

    mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    //mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    File picDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/TrouwApp");
    picDirectory.mkdirs();

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/TrouwApp", "Videos");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
        }
    }

    mrec.setOutputFile( mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator  + date + "_" + videonr+ ".3gp"); 

    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();//line 136

    Log.d(TAG, "Recording started!!");
}
```

lines added to the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

errorlog:

```
 08-25 23:25:25.332: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setup
08-25 23:25:25.362: V/MediaRecorder(4989): constructor
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): doCleanUp
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setListener
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder E: mr = mr
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder X
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): JNIMediaRecorderListener::setCamera
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setCamera(0x16c2290,0x1c08dc8)
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setVideoSource(1)
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setVideoSource(1)
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): Call init() since the media recorder is not initialized yet
08-25 23:25:25.402: V/MediaRecorder(4989): init
08-25 23:25:25.412: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.412: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setAudioSource(1)
08-25 23:25:25.412: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.412: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setAudioSource(1)
08-25 23:25:25.412: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setOutputFormat(2)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setOutputFormat(2)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setVideoFrameRate(30)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setVideoFrameRate(30)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setVideoSize(1920, 1088)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setVideoSize(1920, 1088)
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setParameter()
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.502: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setParameters(video-param-encoding-bitrate=12000000)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setVideoEncoder(2)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setVideoEncoder(2)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setParameter()
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setParameters(audio-param-encoding-bitrate=96000)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setParameter()
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setParameters(audio-param-number-of-channels=1)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setParameter()
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setParameters(audio-param-sampling-rate=48000)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setAudioEncoder(3)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setAudioEncoder(3)
08-25 23:25:25.512: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setOutputFile
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setOutputFile(60, 0, 0)
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): prepare
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorder(4989): prepare
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.542: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): start
08-25 23:25:25.552: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:25.552: V/MediaRecorder(4989): start
08-25 23:25:25.562: E/MediaRecorder(4989): start failed: -19
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): process_media_recorder_call
08-25 23:25:25.562: E/MediaRecorder(4989): start failed.
08-25 23:25:25.562: E/MediaRecorder(4989): try to delete broken file: /mnt/sdcard/TrouwApp/Videos/25-8-2013_0.3gp
08-25 23:25:25.562: D/videoActivity(4989): ERROR start failed.
08-25 23:25:25.562: D/videoActivity(4989): ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
08-25 23:25:25.562: D/videoActivity(4989): ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): release
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder E: mr = null
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder X
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorder(4989): setListener
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorder(4989): release
08-25 23:25:25.562: V/MediaRecorder(4989): destructor
08-25 23:25:25.562: D/videoActivity(4989): START RECORDING ERROR
08-25 23:25:25.562: W/System.err(4989): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:712)
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at com.example.trouwapp.VideoActivity.startRecording(VideoActivity.java:136)
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at com.example.trouwapp.VideoActivity.onClick(VideoActivity.java:246)
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
08-25 23:25:25.572: W/System.err(4989):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-25 23:25:25.582: W/System.err(4989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-25 23:25:25.592: W/System.err(4989):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 23:25:55.582: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): native_reset
08-25 23:25:55.582: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): getMediaRecorder E
08-25 23:25:55.582: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): release
08-25 23:25:55.582: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder E: mr = null
08-25 23:25:55.582: V/MediaRecorderJNI(4989): setMediaRecorder X
08-25 23:25:56.002: D/AndroidRuntime(4989): Shutting down VM
08-25 23:25:56.002: W/dalvikvm(4989): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac8228)
```

Comment: What is mCamera?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android MediaRecorder - "start failed: -19"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496969/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the solution.
Since i'm using the front camera, I need the get the camcorder profile from the front camera.
I achieved thas by doing this:

```
mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

Instead of this:

```
mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

Comment: Prefer using Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT as 1

Comment: No, camera ID and CameraInfo.facing are two different things! To get the right ID you should iterate over camera infos and check which has CameraInfo.facing equal to CAMERA_FACING_FRONT.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
StartRecording = false;

    if( mrec == null ) { 
        mrec = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
        File picDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/TrouwApp");
        picDirectory.mkdirs();
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/TrouwApp", "Videos");
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); //you forgot this
        mrec.setOutputFile( mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator  + date + "_" + videonr+ ".3gp"); 
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); //you forgot this also
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    }
    if(!StartRecording) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Recording stopped!!");
        try {
            mrec.prepare();
            mrec.start();
            StartRecording = true;
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Recording started!!");
        StartRecording = false;
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.reset();
        mrec.release();
        mrec = null;
    }//else
```

Comment: This is exact the same