# How to record video from front facing camera in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using following code in an Android application written in Xamarin:

```
var recorder = new MediaRecorder ();
recorder.SetVideoSource (VideoSource.Camera); 
recorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Mic);              
recorder.SetOutputFormat (OutputFormat.Default);
recorder.SetVideoEncoder (VideoEncoder.Default); 
recorder.SetAudioEncoder (AudioEncoder.Default);      
recorder.SetOutputFile (path);       
recorder.SetPreviewDisplay (video.Holder.Surface);         
recorder.Prepare ();
recorder.Start ();
```

It works but i have a problem. It uses background camera and orientation is landscape. How can I use front facing camera for recording the video and set orientation to portrait ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

First make sure your minimum supported API version is Gingerbread 2.3

Second ensure all permissions have been added to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And use this snippet to get reference to front camera and display the preview in video view while recording

```
if (Camera.NumberOfCameras < 2) {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "Front camera missing", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        return;
}

_camera = Camera.Open (1);
_camera.SetDisplayOrientation (90);
_camera.Unlock ();

recorder = new MediaRecorder ();

recorder.SetCamera (_camera);

recorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Mic);    
recorder.SetVideoSource (VideoSource.Camera); 

recorder.SetOutputFormat (OutputFormat.Default);
recorder.SetAudioEncoder (AudioEncoder.Default);
recorder.SetVideoEncoder (VideoEncoder.Default);

recorder.SetOutputFile (path);       

recorder.SetOrientationHint (270);

recorder.SetPreviewDisplay (previewVideoView.Holder.Surface);         
recorder.Prepare ();
recorder.Start ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Android can't record video with Front Facing Camera, MediaRecorder start failed: -19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681703/android-cant-record-video-with-front-facing-camera-mediarecorder-start-failed)

> First, make sure that your permissions are set up correctly.
>   Specifically, to record video, you'll want:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission
```

> android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> Second,
>   and this is the tricky part, this line from the tutorial does not work
>   with the front-facing camera!

```
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

> That signature for CamcorderProfile.get() defaults to a profile for
>   the back-facing camera:
>
> Returns the camcorder profile for the first back-facing camera on the
>   device at the given quality level. If the device has no back-facing
>   camera, this returns null.
>
> Instead, use
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#get(int,%20int).
>   The first parameter is the id of the camera that you opened,
>   specifically, the front-facing camera.

Comment: The suggested API CamcorderProfile.get(int, int) is not present in xamarin

Comment: the equivalent is CamcorderProfile.get(int, CamcorderQuality). when mapping the native APIs, Xamarin tries to replace dumb Android int constants with enums where they can (which is awesome)

Comment: What i meant was: CamcorderProfile.Get (1, CamcorderQuality) throws an error in Xamarin - 'No overload for method 'Get' takes 2 arguments'

Answer (score 0):

I used @Kartik's solution with a small modification. Not all devices have a rear facing camera(2012 Nexus 7 is a great example). This verison of the code goes through all available cameras and checks if the camera is truly the front one.

```
for (int camIndex = 0; camIndex < Camera.NumberOfCameras; camIndex++)
{
  Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
  Camera.GetCameraInfo(camIndex, cameraInfo);
  if (cameraInfo.Facing == CameraFacing.Front)
  {
    try
    {
      _camera = Camera.Open(camIndex);
      _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(270);
      _camera.Unlock();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       Toast.MakeText(this, "Front camera missing", ToastLength.Long).Show();
     }
   }
 }
```