# Record video front facing camera using API 16

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

So i tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android) and also [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681703/android-cant-record-video-with-front-facing-camera-mediarecorder-start-failed). Then I also [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) available on API 21 and above...so I'm thinking is there a way for API 16 recording on Front Facing. The methods I saw on link I tried and only worked for the rear camera. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are several answers on the first question that explicitly list which camera to use - you can adapt those to use a front-facing camera ID instead.

Comment: To my understanding, the part that says setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));  is what you change to make it front facing, however no matter what camera profile I use (.QUALITY_ LOW etc) the REAR only comes out. I am wondering is it phone specific?