# cut a video file into many images and combine it in Android

Tags: android, image, video

I just started to study android so I barely know android library.
Would you introduce some library so I can figure out the problem?

The reason I'm trying it is that there is no available parameter to manage shutter speed.
I would like to exposure image sensor a long time but I found it's not supported by firmware.

So I planned to record a video and cut it. Then, combine it together so it would be like long shutter speed picture.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Check out [this](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/) regarding how to edit videos,extract image frames from video or create fast motion video using ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do.
How capturing multiple frames will allow you to simulate different shutter speed.
Assuming you know what you're doing, check out [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android).

You can start recording for any time period you want, save all the images to files/memory and then do whatever you want with the frames.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I meant that there is no parameter to manage shutter speed so I can't take slow shutter speed photos

By cutting a video into many frames and combining them in one picture, I could mimic like a slow shutter speed picture

The result may seem like a slow shutter speed picture

Comment: I guess it helped.
I wanted to know what libraries I can use.
Thank you :)