# Custom Video Recording Screen

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, android-camera-intent

I am trying to implement an application which when starts starts video recording automatically with my custom video recording screen with my own button to stop the recording and with other buttons. What I have done is designed the layout with buttons till now but how to add video recording screen in the background..Please help.!

Comment: Check this link it may help you to make is custom video recording. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile;
    private Camera camera;
    boolean recording = false;
    boolean usecamera = true;
    boolean previewRunning = false;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    File root;
    File file;
    Boolean isSDPresent;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    String timeStamp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initComs();
        actionListener();
    }

    private void initComs() {
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        timeStamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    }

    public static float megabytesAvailable(File f) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
                * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024.f * 1024.f);
    }



    private void actionListener() {
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (recording) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    if (usecamera) {
                        try {
                            camera.reconnect();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // recorder.release();
                    recording = false;
                    // Let's prepareRecorder so we can record again
                    prepareRecorder();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        if (usecamera) {
            camera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
        }
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4) {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        } else if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4) {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        } else {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        }

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        System.out.println("onsurfacecreated");

        if (usecamera) {
            camera = Camera.open();

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        System.out.println("onsurface changed");

        if (!recording && usecamera) {
            if (previewRunning) {
                camera.stopPreview();
            }

            try {
                Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

                p.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth,
                        camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);
                p.setPreviewFrameRate(camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate);

                camera.setParameters(p);

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prepareRecorder();
            if (!recording) {
                recording = true;
                recorder.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        if (usecamera) {
            previewRunning = false;
            // camera.lock();
            camera.release();
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your xml too..@Rishabh

Comment: thnx a lot....please vote up if it worked for you and if not then i will tell you what I exactly used to obtain the functionality I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Rishabh can you post your surface view xml?

Comment: I am getting error while i am trying to use it.I am getting setParameters failed error.

Answer (score 4):

***You can create your own Video Recording Screen***

Try like this, First Create a Custom Recorder using `SurfaceView`

```
public class VideoCapture extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    public Context context;
    private Camera camera;
    public static String videoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() +"/YOUR_VIDEO.mp4";

    public VideoCapture(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public VideoCapture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VideoCapture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void init() {
        try {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            camera = getCameraInstance();
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7)
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            recorder.setOutputFile(videoPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder mHolder) {
        try {
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopCapturingVideo() {
        try {
            recorder.stop();
            camera.lock();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(5)
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if (recorder != null) {
            stopCapturingVideo();
            recorder.release();
            camera.lock();
            camera.release();
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

And you can use it inside your Layout for Activity Class

```
<your_package.VideoCapture
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00000000" />
```

EDITED:-

```
public class CaptureVideo extends Activity {

    private VideoCapture videoCapture;
    private Button stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_capture);
        videoCapture = (VideoCapture) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                videoCapture.stopCapturingVideo();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: ok so this is working but where and how to take the click events?camera recording start and stop?

Comment: yes i will surely do it....i saw the method to stop but am not getting a way to start it....

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava if you call CaptureVideo Activity the recording will be started. Or else you can control from surfaceCreated() method, where recorder.prepare(); recorder.start(); are there..

Comment: Thanks a lot...will let you know if i face a problem/

Comment: Although its fine but it is raising an exception when the video is stopped plus it is replacing the previously stored file and last thing is that the gallery is refreshed after the device is restatred not with the recording. i tried using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
     new String[] { videoPath.toString() }, null,
     new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
       Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
       Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
      } in the stop video but doesnt work.

Comment: video is saved but cannot be played..... dialog message is "Can't play this video"

Answer (score 1):

This way is using fragments:

```
public class CaptureVideo extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private Button btnStartRec;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean recording = false;
    private int randomNum;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     } 

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {      
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     }  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view001 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture_video,container,false);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        initRecorder();        
        btnStartRec = (Button) view001.findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
        btnStartRec.setOnClickListener(this);
        SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView)view001.findViewById(R.id.surfaceCamera);
        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
        cameraView.setClickable(true);
        cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);        

        return view001;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "SdCardPath", "NewApi" })
    private void initRecorder() {

        Random rn = new Random();
        int maximum = 10000000;
        int minimum = 00000001;
        int range = maximum  - minimum  + 1;
        randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum + 1 - 10;        

        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            recorder.setOrientationHint(90);//plays the video correctly
        }else{
            recorder.setOrientationHint(180);
        }


        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/MediaAppVideos/"+randomNum+".mp4");

    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //finish();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCaptureVideo:          
                try{
                    if (recording) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recording = false;
                        // Let's initRecorder so we can record again
                        //initRecorder();
                        //prepareRecorder();
                    } else {
                        recording = true;
                        recorder.start();                   
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){

                }

        default:
            break;

        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        prepareRecorder();
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (recording) {
                recorder.stop();
                recording = false;
            }
            recorder.release();
            // finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }


}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceCamera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCaptureVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start Recording" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't capturing audio. I have granted audio record permissions to the app. What could be the reason ?