# Android - MediaRecorder start() throw IllegalStateException

Tags: android

I am working on an App that requires recording a video

Here's my partial code

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/youraudiofile.3gp";
mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();
mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
try {
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code threw IllegalStateException. I have every permission entered in AndroidManifest.xml , I am very sure there's nothing wrong in AndroidManifest.xml.

I have read several solution but none of them working. How can I solve this problem?

log cat provided below

```
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3624)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4117)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3619)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    ... 11 more
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    at com.example.camera2.CameraView.startRecording(CameraView.java:149)
11-09 20:47:39.787: E/AndroidRuntime(29000):    ... 14 more
```

The modified code as follow, even if the setOutputFormat(), setVideoSource(), setAudioSource() appears just above the if {} , setProfile() will throw a RunTimeException.
The following code will throw an IllegalStateException same as the previous log

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/youraudiofile.3gp";
    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    } else {

        if (! isFrontCamera) {
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            mRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        } else {
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(findFrontFacingCamera(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
            mRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
        }

        mRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
    }
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: ok..i will run it wait..

Comment: Updated, if I use some of the options I used in previous code before the If, the setProfile wont work, why?

Comment: just check this best example for recordng..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android

Comment: After checking it and following your solution, it worked for back camera, however, it does not work for the front.
Some codes are modified by following your example, but this is another question, I will try to solve it.

Comment: Hi, can u please help regarding this issue if u solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove this line and check once..

```
mRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
```

some of your settings are not worked befor 3.0 so set them like this..

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

    } else {

        if (! isFrontCamera) {
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        } else {
            CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(mFrontCamId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
    }
```

Comment: After following your solution, the error I got is same. Not sure what has gone wrong or maybe I am still a novice. I will update my codes shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in your manifest these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" / >
```

Comment: Everything is added as I stated in one of my statement

Comment: ok. 1) see, does your hardware support these formats(+ output format), what you defined. 2)try remove setVideoFrameRate

Comment: ok, next posible solution: try remove all quality settings/formats and add this .setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH)); or .setProfile(1, CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));