# android: how to continue recording video even after screen turned off?

Tags: android, video

some apps like [Secret Video recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aes.secretvideorecorder) can record a video even when the display is turned off. Does anyone know how this is possible? until now i only tried to record with MediaRecorder and when the screen is turned off, the video will show just black. Should i use another method or what's the trick?

Comment: Use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397382/android-app-video-recording-when-screen-off) for more informations.

Comment: i do use a service

Comment: Did you check the linked question. There is a code example how to do what you want.