# How to keep recording video when device is locked?

Tags: android, video, video-recording

I'm working on a video recording app designed to keep recording despite interruptions (phone calls, etc.). My use case would be a user in the app pushing a button on screen to start a recording, and then at some later time manually locking the phone. I'm trying to keep the app recording video even while the phone is locked.

On devices running earlier versions of Android (tested on Android 4.1, DROID 4), the video recording keeps going when the phone has been locked. Testing on various devices, I have been unable to get the video to continue recording on any Android version past 4.1. On devices past 4.1, the video stops recording, but the audio still continues recording, while the last video frame stays on screen.

Is there any way to keep the app recording when the user locks the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, lock screen does not affect the working of services in an application. So if you use a service, then your recording will proceed. check out this link for more information:

[Android app video recording when screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397382/android-app-video-recording-when-screen-off)