# Android Intent Camera - setting bit rate

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am using below code to capture using Camera of the handset. But I don't know how to set the bit rate. Please suggest how to set bit rate

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
  fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
  // set video quality
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

There is no paramter like MediaStore.EXTRA_BITRATE

So what do I do to control bit rate ??

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android) is a better example to record a video using MediaRecorder class. Also inorder to set the Bitrate you can use 
 `setVideoEncodingBitRate(int bitRate)` . which sets the video encoding bit rate for recording. Call this method before `prepare().` For further info, refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes using MediaRecorder I can. That I have already done