# How to control video capture properties in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am capturing video using the following intent:

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
       takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
       startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURE_INTENT);
    }
```

I need to control two things, first its frames sizes with the given **height/width** and secondly I want to capture the video **without audio**.