# Is there any possibilities to hide pause button from camera in android

Tags: android

I want to record the video along with timer.I have implementing to record the video by using the below coding.And also set the timer limit.All of them working fine.But i don't want to stop or pause the timer after it starts.Is there any possibilities to hide the pause button or not to stop the timer during recording.

```
 public void getPhotoFromCamera() {

        if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()&&!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForRecord()) {
            marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();

            marshMallowPermission. requestPermissionForRecord();
        } else {
            if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
                marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
            } else {
                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                takeVideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
                takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);

       /* imgag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgag1.startAnimation(animFadein);*/

                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create your own custom camera activity to record video

Comment: I have created custom camera but not record properly for versions

Comment: well that is realy gonna take some  time to make a perfect video cam you can find it from github ,u surely wil get a perfect video recorder app source

Comment: infact u must try the samples provided by google

Comment: for example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder

Comment: or the accepted answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android

Comment: ok lets try your answer

Comment: I have tried the video record at first time only @AdeelTurk

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do so using the video capture intent.  The reason is that the intent is starting an Activity in an app.  Its not a built in part of the framework, its whatever app says it can capture video.  It can and does differ between OEMs.  So they would all need to agree on a set of extras to implement those behaviors, and that's never happened.  ANd at this point in time even if they did it would take years before it could be counted on working most of the time.

You could however write a custom video capture activity if you wanted to.  I wouldn't suggest it unless its a really important feature for you, its a lot of work to get right.